# How do i add a firebase listener that would wait until firebase auth has loaded?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser == null)
        document.getElementById("loggedOut").hidden = false;

    else
        document.getElementById("loggedIn").hidden = false;    
});
```

it takes the firebase auth data base a second load so when I run this code it will always say that `firebase.auth().currentUser == null` is true.
Even though if I get a button to print `firebase.auth().currentUser` it'll give me the real answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an auth state listener to get a callback when the current user is known, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
  }
});
```

`firebase.auth().currentUser` isn't going to be accurate until the first time this callback is invoked, so you should depend on this callback to render your UI correctly.